# Allow selection of video format from media foundation capture device

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

I have taken the windows CaptureManager code ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/simplecapture-sample ) as a starting point and am trying to allow selection of the available video formats from the capture device.  If I select the first item (default format) the preview works fine, but if I select one of the other formats I get either very fuzzy video or no preview. I can both preview and capture from the default index.

I can enumerate the available video formats.  I am restricting my selections to only the FORMAT_VideoInfo2 types which should be the Media Foundation formats.  I store these into a class and record the actual Index number as part of this class so I can use it to select the desired format later.

```cpp
    TWCameraFormats EnumerateCaptureFormats(IMFMediaSource * pSource)
    {
        IMFPresentationDescriptor * pPD = NULL;
        IMFStreamDescriptor *       pSD = NULL;
        IMFMediaTypeHandler *       pHandler = NULL;
        IMFMediaType *              pType = NULL;
        GUID                        guidSubType = GUID_NULL;
        GUID                        guidMediaType = GUID_NULL;
        DWORD                       cTypes = 0;
        BOOL                        fSelected;
        UINT32                      count = 0;
        UINT32                      value1;
        UINT32                      value2;
        TWCameraFormats             CameraFormats;
        DWORD                       ItemIndex = 0;

        CameraFormats.set_length(0);

        HRESULT hr = pSource->CreatePresentationDescriptor(&pPD);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }

        hr = pPD->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(0, &fSelected, &pSD);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }

        hr = pSD->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pHandler);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }

        hr = pHandler->GetMediaTypeCount(&cTypes);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }

        for (DWORD typeIndex = 0; typeIndex < cTypes; typeIndex++)
        {
            hr = pHandler->GetMediaTypeByIndex(typeIndex, &pType);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                goto done;
            }

            HRESULT hr = pType->GetCount(&count);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                goto done;
            }

            if (count == 0)
            {
                goto done;
            }

            hr = pType->GetGUID(MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE, &guidMediaType);
            if(FAILED(hr))
            {
                break;
            }

            if (guidMediaType == FORMAT_VideoInfo2)
            {
                TWCameraFormat * CurrentFormat;
                CameraFormats.set_length(ItemIndex + 1);
                CurrentFormat = &CameraFormats[ItemIndex++];
                CurrentFormat->Index = typeIndex;

                hr = GetFrameSize(pType, &value1, &value2);
                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    break;
                }
                CurrentFormat->Width  = value1;
                CurrentFormat->Height = value2;

                hr = GetFrameRate(pType, &value1, &value2);
                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (value2 > 0)
                {
                    CurrentFormat->AvgTimePerFrame = 10000000 / (value1 / value2);
                }

                hr = pType->GetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &guidSubType);
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    break;
                }

                CurrentFormat->BitsPerPixel = 0;
                if (guidSubType == MFVideoFormat_YUY2)
                {
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[0] = 'Y';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[1] = 'U';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[2] = 'Y';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[3] = '2';
                    CurrentFormat->BitsPerPixel   = 24;
                }
                else if (guidSubType == MFVideoFormat_H264)
                {
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[0] = 'H';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[1] = '2';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[2] = '6';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[3] = '4';
                    CurrentFormat->BitsPerPixel   = 32;
                }
                else if (guidSubType == MFVideoFormat_H265)
                {
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[0] = 'H';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[1] = '2';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[2] = '6';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[3] = '5';
                    CurrentFormat->BitsPerPixel   = 32;
                }
                else if (guidSubType == MFVideoFormat_MJPG)
                {
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[0] = 'M';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[1] = 'J';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[2] = 'P';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[3] = 'G';
                    CurrentFormat->BitsPerPixel   = 32;
                }
                else if (guidSubType == MFVideoFormat_NV12)
                {
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[0] = 'N';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[1] = 'V';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[2] = '1';
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[3] = '2';
                    CurrentFormat->BitsPerPixel   = 12;
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[3] = (guidSubType.Data1 >> 24)  & 0xFF;
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[2] = (guidSubType.Data1 >> 16)  & 0xFF;
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[1] = (guidSubType.Data1 >>  8)  & 0xFF;
                    CurrentFormat->Compression[0] = (guidSubType.Data1 >>  0)  & 0xFF;
                }
            }

            SafeRelease(&pType);
        }

    done:
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            CameraFormats.set_length(0);
        }
        SafeRelease(&pPD);
        SafeRelease(&pSD);
        SafeRelease(&pHandler);
        SafeRelease(&pType);
        return CameraFormats;
    }
```

In the capture manager I pass the Index from the format enumeration and use this to select the desired video format.

```cpp
    HRESULT CaptureManager::SetVideoFormat(int FormatIndex)
    {
        IMFPresentationDescriptor * pPD = NULL;
        IMFStreamDescriptor *       pSD = NULL;
        IMFMediaTypeHandler *       pHandler = NULL;
        IMFMediaType *              pType = NULL;
        IMFCaptureSource  *         pCaptureSource = NULL;
        IMFMediaSource    *         pSource = NULL;

        HRESULT hr = m_pEngine->GetSource(&pCaptureSource);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }

        hr = pCaptureSource->GetCaptureDeviceSource(MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_DEVICE_TYPE_VIDEO, &pSource);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }

        hr = pSource->CreatePresentationDescriptor(&pPD);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }

        BOOL fSelected;
        hr = pPD->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(0, &fSelected, &pSD);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }

        hr = pSD->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pHandler);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }

        hr = pHandler->GetMediaTypeByIndex(FormatIndex, &pType);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }

        hr = pHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pType);

    done:
        SafeRelease(&pPD);
        SafeRelease(&pSD);
        SafeRelease(&pHandler);
        SafeRelease(&pType);
        return hr;
    }
```

And then I activate the preview from the capture manager.

```cpp
    HRESULT CaptureManager::StartPreview()
    {
        if (m_pEngine == NULL)
        {
            return MF_E_NOT_INITIALIZED;
        }

        if (m_bPreviewing == true)
        {
            return S_OK;
        }

        IMFCaptureSink *pSink = NULL;
        IMFMediaType *pMediaType = NULL;
        IMFMediaType *pMediaType2 = NULL;
        IMFCaptureSource *pSource = NULL;

        HRESULT hr = S_OK;

        // Get a pointer to the preview sink.
        if (m_pPreview == NULL)
        {
            hr = m_pEngine->GetSink(MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_SINK_TYPE_PREVIEW, &pSink);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                goto done;
            }

            hr = pSink->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pPreview));
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                goto done;
            }

            hr = m_pPreview->SetRenderHandle(m_hwndPreview);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                goto done;
            }

            hr = m_pEngine->GetSource(&pSource);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                goto done;
            }

            // Configure the video format for the preview sink.
            hr = pSource->GetCurrentDeviceMediaType((DWORD)MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_PREFERRED_SOURCE_STREAM_FOR_VIDEO_PREVIEW , &pMediaType);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                goto done;
            }

            hr = CloneVideoMediaType(pMediaType, MFVideoFormat_RGB32, &pMediaType2);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                goto done;
            }

            hr = pMediaType2->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                goto done;
            }

            // Connect the video stream to the preview sink.
            DWORD dwSinkStreamIndex;
            hr = m_pPreview->AddStream((DWORD)MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_PREFERRED_SOURCE_STREAM_FOR_VIDEO_PREVIEW,  pMediaType2, NULL, &dwSinkStreamIndex);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                goto done;
            }
        }


        hr = m_pEngine->StartPreview();
        if (!m_fPowerRequestSet && m_hpwrRequest != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            // NOTE:  By calling this, on SOC systems (AOAC enabled), we're asking the system to not go
            // into sleep/connected standby while we're streaming.  However, since we don't want to block
            // the device from ever entering connected standby/sleep, we're going to latch ourselves to
            // the monitor on/off notification (RegisterPowerSettingNotification(GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON)).
            // On SOC systems, this notification will fire when the user decides to put the device in
            // connected standby mode--we can trap this, turn off our media streams and clear this
            // power set request to allow the device to go into the lower power state.
            m_fPowerRequestSet = (TRUE == PowerSetRequest(m_hpwrRequest, PowerRequestExecutionRequired));
        }
    done:
        SafeRelease(&pSink);
        SafeRelease(&pMediaType);
        SafeRelease(&pMediaType2);
        SafeRelease(&pSource);

        return hr;
    }
```

All of the functions return valid codes but my preview will only work reliably for the first item in the index.

I create a new CaptureManager whenever I connect for a new format, so nothing should be retained from previous session.

Comment: Just an update to this. I have found that if I select a NV12 format I can connect and this displays okay, f I disconnect and select another NV12 format the video changes to this format.  However, if I select an MJPG format the video is not displayed and any subsequent attempts to display an NV12 format will also fail.

Comment: Just a further update to this. I have found that if I select a NV12 or YUY2 format I can connect and this displays okay, if I disconnect and select another NV12 or YUY2 format the video stays on the original.  However, if I select an MJPG format the video is not displayed and any subsequent attempts to display an NV12 or YUY2 format will also fail, even though I destroy the capture engine and create a new one each time I connect to the capture device.